# Why sh script generates "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run: "npm run test" on Node.js.
OS: Win10.
Getting error:

```
node_modules\.bin\wdio:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Comment: You probably run it using Command Prompt or PowerShell. `dirname` is a Un*x tool, it is not available by default on Windows. You need either WSL or a Unix compatibility layer and the Unix tools compiled for Windows (Cygwin, MinGW).

Comment: Looks l used old Node.js command reference: " node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./wdio.conf.js". Using "npx wdio run ./wdio.conf.js" solved the issue. Thank You, k